# Where does this coupling result use independence when bounding total variational distance?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I am reading [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3315038), which gives the following coupling result:

Throughout this, I'll assume the dimension $k$ is clear. Let $e_i$ be the $i$-th basis in the $k$ dimensional standard basis.

A $k$ dimensional random variable $X$ is a multinomial bernoulli random variable if it is parameterized by $p \in [0,1]^k$ such that $X \in \{{\bf 0}, e_1, ..., e_k\}$ with $\Pr[X=e_i]=p_i$ and $\Pr[X={\bf 0}]=1-\sum_i p_i$.

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n $ be **independent** multinomial bernoulli random variables parameterized by $p_1, ..., p_n$. Let $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ be $k$ dimensional poisson random variables where dimension $j$ of $Y_i$ is an independent Poisson $\text{Poisson}(p_{i,j})$.

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $T_n = \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j$. Then the total variational distance $d(S_n, T_n)$ has the bound

$$d(S_n, T_n) = \sup_A |\Pr(S_n \in A)-\Pr(T_n \in A)| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=1}^k p_{i,j} \right)^2$$

---

**Question**:

The proof is fairly short. First, they use the fact that $d(X, Y)\leq \Pr[X\neq Y]$. So we have

$$d(S_n, T_n) \leq \Pr[S_n \neq T_n] \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr[X_i \neq Y_i]$$ (where the last inequality uses union bound, or Boole's inequality). By using maximum coupling on $(X_i, Y_i)$, we get $\Pr[X_i \neq Y_i] \leq \Pr[X_i^\ast \neq Y_i^\ast]=d(X_i, Y_i)$. Finally, they bound $d(X_i, Y_i) \leq \left( \sum_{j=1}^k p_{i,j} \right)^2$.

**My question is, where in this proof does it use independence of** $X_1, ..., X_n$? Specifically, union bound does not require independence?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is of course incorrect. In particular, the inequality $\Pr[X_i \neq Y_i] \leq \Pr[X_i^\ast \neq Y_i^\ast]$ actually goes in the opposite direction (this inequality does not seem to be in the paper linked in your post).

A correct proof is as follows. For each $i$, let $(X_i^*,Y_i^*)$ be the closest coupling of $(X_i,Y_i)$, so that $d(X_i,Y_i)=P(X_i^*\ne Y_i^*)$. Suppose also that the random pairs $(X_i^*,Y_i^*)$ are independent. Let $S_n^*:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^*$ and $T_n^*:=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^*$. Then $S_n^*$ equals $S_n$ in distribution and $T_n^*$ equals $T_n$ in distribution (because the $X_i$'s are independent and the $Y_i$'s are independent). So,
\begin{equation}
    d(S_n,T_n)=d(S_n^*,T_n^*)\le P(S_n^*\ne T_n^*)\le\sum_{i=1}^n P(X_i^*\ne Y_i^*)
    =\sum_{i=1}^n d(X_i,Y_i). 
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still a bit confused how independence implies $S_n^\ast$ equals $S_n$ in distribution? (I just learned about coupling recently, so this might be an obvious question).

Comment: @AspiringMat : The $X_i$'s are independent and the $X_i^*$'s are independent and each $X_i^*$ equals $X_i$ in distribution. So, $(X_1^*,\dots,X_n^*)$ equals $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ in distribution. So, $S_n^*=X_i^*+\dots+X_n^*$ equals $S_n=X_i+\dots+X_n$ in distribution.

Comment: I see I misunderstood their proof. They were actually doing what you're doing (but it's not as clear as your writing). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks I accepted it (I previously upvoted it)